# Use of right string function

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to list a few details from a certain table, where two columns end with a certain number, and I must use the RIGHT string function.

Using MySQL Workbench

So far I have:

```
Select dog_id, Cat_id, Place
FROM EVENT_ENTRY
```

In the columns dog_id and cat_id, there is data such as 501, 502, 401, 301, 201, 101, 91 etc.

I need to list all of the data from both dog_id and cat_id that ends with 1, using the right string function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, using mySQL Workbench.

Comment: .... WHERE RIGHT(dog_id,1) = '1' AND RIGHT(cat_id,1) = '1' ...

Comment: Did do a search prior to posting this, but didn't come across that.

Comment: Are dod_id and cat_id really strings? Why has it to be the RIGHT function?  I would do something like WHERE dog_id % 10 = 1 AND cat_id % 10 = 1 ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dog_id, Cat_id, Place FROM EVENT_ENTRY 
WHERE RIGHT(dog_id, LEN(dog_id)) = 1 AND RIGHT(cat_id, LEN(cat_id))
```

Comment: Right second parameter should be 1 and not the length of the string it gets. `RIGHT(dog_id, LEN(dog_id))` is the same as `dog_id`

Answer (score 0):

If these are int columns (or any other integer data type for that matter), it's better to test if [modulu](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) 2 = 1, like this: `WHERE Dog_Id % 2 = 1 AND Cat_Id % 2 = 1`

If these are string columns (nchar, nvarchar etc.), you can use the [right](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function, like this: `WHERE RIGHT(Dog_Id, 1) = '1' AND RIGHT(Cat_Id, 1) = '1'`,
or use like with a wildcard, like this: `WHERE Dog_Id LIKE '%1' AND Cat_Id LIKE '%1'`

Comment: Surely it would be `WHERE Cat_Id % 10 = 1`, and not `WHERE Cat_Id % 2 = 0`? The latter is just retrieving where the number is even.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dog_id, Cat_id, Place
FROM EVENT_ENTRY
WHERE RIGHT(dog_id,1)='1' and RIGHT(cat_id,1)='1';
```